# Ошибка при авторизации в symfony

Tags: php, symfony

С помощью команды `make:auth` создал авторизацию. Заполнил таблицу пользователями. Когда пытаюсь авторизоваться появляется сообщение об ошибке:

```
There is no user provider for user "App\Entity\User". Shouldn't the "supportsClass()" method of your user provider return true for this classname?
```

Что идет не так? Вроде все делал как указано в документации https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Мой security.yaml

```
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Guard (обработка формы)

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage'));


    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

P.S До этого редактировал supportsClass в UserProvider чтобы он не возвращал `false`:

```
{
    return $class === UserIdentity::class;
}
```

Comment: UserIdentity - это какой то ваш класс, который нигде не фигурирует. Вы работаете C Entity/User а проверяете принадлежность провадйера с UserIdentity.

Comment: @Pavel,  пробовал написать так `{return $class === Entity/User::class;}` но ошибка та же самая(

Comment: Так дословно и написали? это я для направления написал. У вас прямо в ошибке написано: "App\Entity\User" . {return $class === App\Entity\User::class;} тогда не знаю. Вроде если по доке все делать - должно быть ок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно либо убрать блок из security.yaml

```
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: null }
```

Либо поменять его на что-то типа

```
providers:
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
```

ну и при таком раскладе добавить provider: app_user_provider в main firewall

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: app_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало. Можете немного объяснить, что именно вы написали? Только-только начал изучать symfony и пока чтобы я не делал, сыпятся ошибки( хотя по теории было все понятно

Comment: У вас в конфиге стоял юзер провайдер in_memory то есть пользователи которых можно описать прям в конфиге, то есть когда вы пытались залогиниться он не обращался к вашй БД для получения пользователей а пытался найти их в security.yaml. А добавление app_user_provider как я написал, как раз показывало где хранятся пользователи и какое поле у энтити будет логином (property: email). У самого фаервола тоже лучше указывать provider: %name%, так как со временем может стать несколько провайдеров и несколько фаерволов, а у симфони если не ошибаюсь есть какая-то своя логика выбора если не указано.